# Static object of nested class

Tags: c++, inner-classes

I have a `Request_manager.h` file declaring an object `Tickets_Queue` as static in `Request_manager`, which is a nested class from itself.

```
class Request_manager {
public:
    class Tickets_Queue{
    private:
        pthread_mutex_t m_mutex;

    public:
        Tickets_Queue(){};
        ~Tickets_Queue(){};
    };
    static Tickets_Queue ticket_queue;

private:
    static int m_connected;
};
```

To initialize it, in `Request_manager.cpp` I write:

```
int Request_manager::m_connected(0);
Request_manager::Tickets_Queue Request_manager::ticket_queue();
```

The initialization of `m_connected` works but for `ticket_queue` it says:

```
gcc.archive core/bin/gcc-5.4.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/libcore.a
gcc.compile.c++ data_interfaces/bin/gcc-5.4.0/debug/link-static/threading-multi/Request_manager.o
data_interfaces/Request_manager.cpp:17:62: error: no ‘dataserver::Request_manager::Tickets_Queue dataserver::Request_manager::ticket_queue()’ member function declared in class ‘dataserver::Request_manager’
 Request_manager::Tickets_Queue Request_manager::ticket_queue();
```

Comment: Why are you using `pthread_mutex_t` instead of `std::mutex`?

Comment: Please, leave out the parentheses `()`. You want to call the default constructor but the compiler reads this as **function declaration**. (A common pitfall I saw often enough.) ;-) Please, try `Request_manager::Tickets_Queue Request_manager::ticket_queue;`. `Request_manager::Tickets_Queue Request_manager::ticket_queue{};` should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You are calling a function.</s>

Yeah. My mistake. As @john says it is *prototyping* a function.

You have to declare the type and the variable:

```
Request_manager::Tickets_Queue Request_manager::ticket_queue;
```

Comment: Not calling a function, prototyping a function.

Comment: @john yes, corrected response. Thanks john.